# How to read XML node from URL using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, url

I'm having program like below. The concept is Read XML value from URL, but my program read the xml structure only, not the code datas. Like `<Billing Address></Billing Address>...` etc only. But the original XML value is `<Billing Address>Strre1</Billing Address>`. The Program does not read the inside value.

```
public static void zohoCRMReadAccounts()
{

    var val = auth();
    var val1= val[0];
    var val2= val[1];

    String xmlURL = "URL";
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                Console.Write("<" + xmlReader.Name);
                // Read the attributes:
                while (xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute()) 
                    Console.Write(" " + xmlReader.Name + "=’" 
                                   + xmlReader.Value + "’");
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                Console.Write("</" + xmlReader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue…");
    Console.ReadLine(); //Pause
}
```

Please help me to fix

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using the complicated `XmlTextReader` and not the much simpler `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` classes?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth If you know any simplest idea , then please share here

Answer (score 1):

XML Elements cannot have spaces in their names. Try to remove them first

Answer (score 0):

First download the XML. Then Use like,

```
  try { 
    //read xml
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load("XMLFilePath");
    XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes(@"rss/channel/item");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
      XmlNode titleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("title");
      string title = titleNode == null ? string.Empty : titleNode.InnerText;

      };
```

}