# How to read the XML using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read XML node from URL using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246449/how-to-read-xml-node-from-url-using-c)

I'm having below XML, I want to read this XML URL using C#

```
<result>
<Accounts>
<row no="1">
<FL val="ACCOUNTID">012345678</FL>
<FL val="SMOWNERID">012345678</FL>
<FL val="Account Owner">
<![CDATA[ demo name]]>
</FL>
<FL val="Account Name">
<![CDATA[ demo ]]>
</FL>
<FL val="Phone">
<![CDATA[ +12 34 5567 345]]>
</FL>
<FL val="Account Site">
<![CDATA[ demo]]>
</FL>
```

I have used below code for reading XML from URL but i'm getting below output in console

```
<FL val="Account Name">
<![CDATA[ demo ]]>
</FL>
<FL val="Phone">
</FL>
<FL val="Account Site">
</FL>
```

My code is below :

```
String xmlURL = "http://localhost/my.xml";
        XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                    Console.Write("<" + xmlReader.Name);

                    while (xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                        Console.Write(" " + xmlReader.Name + "=’" + xmlReader.Value + "’");
                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                    Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                    Console.Write("</" + xmlReader.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue…");
        Console.ReadLine(); //Pause
```

Please help to read the inside data

Comment: Any reason you want to use a low-level XML API instead of the (much simpler) LINQ to XML?

Comment: If you're on .NET 3.5+, you can use [LINQ to XML (XDocument)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx), which I think is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlReader` and subclasses are just about the hardest approach. Unless you need to avoid loading the whole parsed object graph into memory it is better to avoid.

Using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and `XPath` (`using System.Xml.XPath` to get the [extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathevaluate.aspx)) is easier:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var iterator = doc.XPathSelectElements("/result/Accounts/row/FL");
foreach (var flNode in iterator) {
  var text = flNode.Value;
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that xml seems to contain many accounts, and many rows in one account. Flatten all the data is not a good idea.

Comment: @L.B Too much ambiguity in the Q to improve it. Getting all the text seems odd, but that's what the last sentence implies.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using XPath instead of raw XML parsing like you're doing.

Refer to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333) link for more information about XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ2XML..Its **COOL**

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML");
foreach(XElement x in doc.Descendants("results").Descendants("Accounts").Descendants("row").Elements())
{
x.Name;//Its name
x.Attribute("val").Value;//its val attributes value
x.Value;//its value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try create XMLDocument, then populate it with file and in the end pass thgrough in for loop.

```
string output;

XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument(); //create XML document object

myxml.LoadXml("path to your document"); //populate doc with youe doumnet

XmlElement my_xml_element = myxml.DocumentElement; 

XmlAttributeCollection attribute = myElement.Attributes;


foreach (XmlAttributeCollection test_atribute in attribute )
{
   output = test_attribute.Name
}
```